# How to replace showModalDialog when value is being returned

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asp-classic, showmodaldialog

I have a opener window that is currently using showModalDialog. This needs to be replaced because its deprecated. The modal dialog window has a window.returnvalue. As a result, I am unable to simply use Window.Open to replace showModalDialog.

Is there anyway to work around this problem? Below is a sample code
Caller:

```
retval = window.showModalDialog('abc.asp?user=' SomeUser + "center=no;dialogwidth:600px;dialogheight:400px;dialogwidth:600px;dialogheight:400px;help=No;status=yes")
//DO SOMETHING WITH retval
```

Modal Dialog Window:

```
  <script>
  function SaveMe()
  {
      window.returnValue = 'Some value that is needed in caller';
      window.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [windows.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

Call popup:

```
retval = window.open(......);
//bind close event to retval
retval.onunload = getReturnValue;
```

And function `getReturnValue`

```
function getReturnValue(){
//now value is retval.returnValue or something you bind
console.log(retval.returnValue);
}
```

I just fixed my website yesterday.